# How to get feeling or activities which user has posted from facebook api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to fetch activities or feeling using graph API from facebook.

e.g.

```
XYZ is feeling angry.
XYZ is watching movie.
XYZ is feeling happy.
```

Currently I am using time-line API (https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me?fields=posts) which only returns following.

```
XYZ updated his status. (Not getting activity or feeling name)
```

How to get activity or feeling of user?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's graph API doesn't give any access to this data. The best you can do right now is to ask for user_posts and user_status permissions and parse the /me/feed posts manually. But it doesn't give you everything you asked for